# "Overriding" Kernel USB driver in Android

Tags: android, usb-otg

Is it possible to write an app in Android that handles an OTG USB device ([USB Host Mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)), even if that USB device is already supported by a built-in (kernel?) driver?

If so, do I need to do anything special with it? Or will Android automatically bring up the dialog to ask how to treat the device if it sees an application that supports the device in addition to its drivers?

Comment: did you find solution for that, suggest to look out : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=159897

Comment: @boy Not so far, but other things have come up meanwhile, so I haven't spent that much time on it since... Thanks for the link. Not exactly related, but definitely incredibly important to be aware of!